# Same app name but different country and binary

Tags: ios, app-store, submission, country

I have a version of an app that is currently available in the mexico store, but I would like to do a colombia version. The the data used and the UI will change somewhat.

Can I create a different binary to upload to a different store and still keep the same app name?

I found the question above somewhere with no answer, just editted it a little.
I found that question because it is my question now. Can you give me any ideas or advice?

Thanks for anyhelp or advice that you can give.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't upload a different version for each country, but you could detect the users location and then change the UI/whatever else to match what is needed for that locale.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer and advice. I'll try to suggest that we detect the country and automatically change the theme in our meeting.