# In app purchases App Store

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, app-store

Is there a way you can have different level tier prices dependent on users country? For example have a different level tier for US app store and a different price in UK app store.

Comment: Yeah `UK = US * 2 + 10` seems to be the formula you're after :)

Answer (score 0):

As this answer says [Different price for different countries](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4172682/2046606) it is not possible.

It does go on to say that you could create more than 1 of the app and limit it's distribution to different countries depending on the pricing tier you wish to set. (I don't know if this would get rejected by Apple however)

Edit:

[Same app name but different country and binary](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11132739/2046606)

This answer says you can't, which would be the obvious assumption as Apple gives you a way to localise your app without submitting it multiple times.